# GIT_ASKPASS script returning 1 still fallback to terminal prompt

Tags: git

In my script git clones a https repository and I provide the password with a helper script. If the script fails git must **not** prompt for the password interactively.

From GITCREDENTIALS(7)

> ```
>    If a helper outputs a quit attribute with a value of true or 1, no further helpers will be consulted, nor will
>    the user be prompted (if no credential has been provided, the operation will then fail).
> ```

My helper script exits with 1, but git still prompts for the password. What am I doing wrong?

git version 2.34.1.

`fakeaskpass`

```
#!/bin/sh

# test fail
exit 1

{
echo "********** fakepass ************"
echo "$@"

case $* in
*'https://'*'github.com'*)
    PF_SSH_PASS=${GITHUB_TOKEN:?}
    ;;
esac

echo "********** fakepass ************"
} >&2
printf %s "$PF_SSH_PASS"
```

`build.sh`

```
export GIT_ASKPASS="${PWD:?}/fakeaskpass"

</dev/null git clone --depth=1 \
  https://user@github.com/user/repo.git
```

Output:

```
Cloning into 'repo'...
error: unable to read askpass response from '/tmp/fakeaskpass'
Password for 'https://user@github.com':
```